# Toon Shader is all shadows

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I was testing some grass shaders and then wanted to add an object on it with my usual Toon Shader Nodes. However suddenly it's only the shadows and no lighting or anything.

I tried the exact same nodes on a fresh file and it works perfectly.

I checked if the normals are flipped, but they're not.

Why is the shader not working in one of the files?

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell. Toon shaders are still dependent on lighting position/strength. Is your lighting the same in both images? Maybe if you post your file (or a minimal version) we could figure it out more easily. You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Also, I think you can get away with just using a Diffuse BSDF at the beginning of your shader instead of a Principled one.